# Tree view in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I try to create simple TODOList app. Where you can create Project, then create tasks for project, subtasks for tasks and subtasks. I create a template to show task:

```
<li class='task'>
<div class="collapsible-header" id="task-name"> {{task.title}}</div>
<div class="collapsible-body" data-task-pk='{{task.pk}}' id="task-details">
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/control-block.html' %}
    <p>{{task.description}}</p>
    <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="expandable" id="subtasks">
        {% for sub_task in task.subtasks.all %}
           {% include "ProjectManager/views/task_view.html" with task=sub_task %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

You can see i try to create a list of subtask, by using this template recursively, but I got an error:

```
'RecursionError' object has no attribute 'token'
```

I found some informations, that i should use variable to store template name, like this:

```
<li class='task'>
<div class="collapsible-header" id="task-name"> {{task.title}}</div>
<div class="collapsible-body" data-task-pk='{{task.pk}}' id="task-details">
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/control-block.html' %}
    <p>{{task.description}}</p>
    <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="expandable" id="subtasks">
        {% for sub_task in task.subtasks.all %}
            {% with node=sub_task template_name="ProjectManager/views/task_view.html" %}
                {% include template_name with task=node%}
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

I got an error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But at start I wrote wrong:

```
  {% with node=**subtask** template_name="ProjectManager/views/task_view.html" %}
```

And template display list of subtasks with empty elements (without task.title and description).

Then I tried to put some if condition:

```
<li class='task'>
<div class="collapsible-header" id="task-name"> {{task.title}}</div>
<div class="collapsible-body" data-task-pk='{{task.pk}}' id="task-details">
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/control-block.html' %}
    <p>{{task.description}}</p>
    <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="expandable" id="subtasks">
        {% if task.subtasks.all|length %}
            {% for sub_task in task.subtasks.all %}
                {% with node=sub_task template_name="ProjectManager/views/task_view.html" %}
                    {% include template_name with task=node%}
                {% endwith %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
</li>
```

But I got new error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

How can I do this with Django templates? 
Full [traceback](http://dpaste.com/0JKT0QF)

In this way I show tasks list:

```
<div class="card-content">
    <ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="expandable" id="main-tasks">
    {% for task in project.tasks.all %}
        {% include 'ProjectManager/views/task_view.html' with task=task%}
    {%endfor%}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add the names/paths for the views? looks like something is called over and over again. and can you share the exact line the error is thrown?

Comment: @ht_ i wrote errors exactly i saw them in browser, full traceback shown in link. What names and path do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *global* var's name is `task`. But your *local* var is **also** called `task`.

```
{% for task in project.tasks.all %}
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/task_view.html' with task=task%}
{%endfor%}
```

so i guess what you where *trying to do* is:

```
{% for task_local in project.tasks.all %}
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/task_view.html' with task_global_of_next_inheritance=task_local%}
{%endfor%}
```

but what happened is

```
{% for task_local in project.tasks.all %}
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/task_view.html' with task_global_of_next_inheritance=task_global%}
{%endfor%}
```

(using the global instead of the local var)
so you are just making the same call over and over again. if i am right, fix with

```
{% for task_local in project.tasks.all %}
    {% include 'ProjectManager/views/task_view.html' with task=task_local%}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: it's return error: 'RecursionError' object has no attribute 'token'

Comment: i referring to the second error, `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

Comment: if i use second listing i got: `maximum recursion depth exceeded` - error, with third listing i got `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` - error